# When using the latest Monodevelop and VS 2012 RC to share code I get problems

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When using the latest Monodevelop and VS 2012 RC to share code. I can load and use the .sln solution, .csproj project files, and all the code files from either a Mac running MonoDevelop and a Windows 7 PC running the latest VS 2012 beta. The source code is on a share between the machines.

This works really well... but at some stage when I try to reload the solution project under MonoDevelop on the mac MonoDevelop thinks the solution file .sln is a Hex file and loads and displays it hex in a Window. It doesn't think its a solution file anymore!

I notice the file lines are terminated with 0D 0A, which is correct for the PC. . I know the Mac uses just 0D as in ... but its like that initially and works. The contents look fine to me!

If I create a new solution on Mac MonoDevelop then drop the exiting csproj's into it it works fine. Until it doesn't....

Any ideas?

Comment: Did this happen in Visual Studio 2010 already or is this problem new to VS 2012?

Comment: I think I have see it pryor to 2012... but this is the first time I've been doing this in anger.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that the VS SLN files now start with:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

Whereas they need to start with:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

I reported this to Xamarin - and they've already got a patch - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4919

Alternatively, just manually hack the files - that's what I do.

Comment: I have always kept two copies of sln/csproj files (one Mac and one Windows) and just use source control to check them out on both machines.  I think this is generally a better idea because of these kinds of issues.