# How to open visual studio solution in Mono develop

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop

How can I open a Visual Studio 2012 solution in Mono Develop?
Visual Studio hangs when I debugging.

When I tring to open the solution in Mono Develop it just open at text file with a lot of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i remember there has been an issue with this that were fixed in 3.0.6 that is currently in Alpha.

There is a workaround in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049049/when-using-the-latest-monodevelop-and-vs-2012-rc-to-share-code-i-get-problems)